# кто нибудь знает как подключить библиотеку яндекс карты в react?

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api, консоль

столкнулся с проблемой что не могу установить библиотеку react-yandex-maps

во время установки выпадает ошибка   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project

```
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.9 || ^15.x || ^16.x || ^17.x" from react-yandex-maps@4.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-yandex-maps
npm ERR!   react-yandex-maps@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
```

не понимаю как решить эту проблему ,т.к иначе установить яндекс карты(как описано на сайте )у меня не выходит

Comment: Возможно они хотят 14-17 реакт?

Comment: возможно,я не давно начал изучать реакт,тонкостей не знаю,как можно откатить до 14-17 реакт?

Comment: Ну.. Можно конечно погуглить, но думаю что-то типо `npm i react@17`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о несовместимости версии `react-yandex-maps` с React 18.2, и по однозначному заявлению разработчика модуля он не планирует его обновлять.

Попробуйте использовать другой модуль, например https://github.com/R1ZEN/react-yandex-maps

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло понизить версию React на 16.13.1

Answer (score 0):

npm install --force react-yandex-maps

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]